# Need flexible height for overflow div content

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have two div box Left and right... I need flexible listing height in right div box as left box content are not fixed...Means if i add some contents in 'left div box'.. then 'right div box' autoflow content box height should be adjust accordingly   
**Here is a [link](http://jsfiddle.net/aPaf5/1/)**

/*css*/

```
.dvleft{float:left;} .dvright{float:right}.dv100per{width:100%;float:left}
.grey_bg2{padding: 5px 0px 8px 7px;background-color:#F7F7F7;color:#000; font-size:13px}
.mTop5{margin-top:5px;}.mTop10{margin-top:10px}.mTop20{margin-top:20px}.mleft15{margin-left:15px;}
    .contactlist{background-color:#FFF;float:left;width:100%;padding: 5px 0px 10px 0px;height:239px;overflow:auto}
    .sharecon{float:left;width:100%; border-bottom:solid 1px #e6e6e6; padding:3px 0 6px 0}
```

/*HTML*/

```
<div class="dvright grey_bg2 mTop20" style="width: 365px; padding: 7px 8px 10px 8px;">
    <div class="dv100per">
        <span class="dvleft">
            <strong>Right Box</strong>
        </span>
    </div>

        <div class="contactlist">
            <div class="sharecon">
                <span class="dvleft">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox">
                </span>

                <span class="dvleft mleft15">
                    <strong class="text11">abc123..</strong>
                </span>
                <span class="dvleft mleft15">abc123@gmail.com</span>

            </div><!--sharecon-->
            <div class="sharecon">
                <span class="dvleft">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox">
                </span>

                <span class="dvleft mleft15">
                    <strong class="text11">abc123..</strong>
                </span>
                <span class="dvleft mleft15">abc123@gmail.com</span>

            </div><!--sharecon-->
            <div class="sharecon">
                <span class="dvleft">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox">
                </span>

                <span class="dvleft mleft15">
                    <strong class="text11">abc123..</strong>
                </span>
                <span class="dvleft mleft15">abc123@gmail.com</span>

            </div><!--sharecon-->
            <div class="sharecon">
                <span class="dvleft">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox">
                </span>

                <span class="dvleft mleft15">
                    <strong class="text11">abc123..</strong>
                </span>
                <span class="dvleft mleft15">abc123@gmail.com</span>

            </div><!--sharecon-->
            <div class="sharecon">
                <span class="dvleft">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox">
                </span>

                <span class="dvleft mleft15">
                    <strong class="text11">abc123..</strong>
                </span>
                <span class="dvleft mleft15">abc123@gmail.com</span>

            </div><!--sharecon-->
            <div class="sharecon">
                <span class="dvleft">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox">
                </span>

                <span class="dvleft mleft15">
                    <strong class="text11">abc123..</strong>
                </span>
                <span class="dvleft mleft15">abc123@gmail.com</span>

            </div><!--sharecon-->
            <div class="sharecon">
                <span class="dvleft">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox">
                </span>

                <span class="dvleft mleft15">
                    <strong class="text11">abc123..</strong>
                </span>
                <span class="dvleft mleft15">abc123@gmail.com</span>

            </div><!--sharecon-->
            <div class="sharecon">
                <span class="dvleft">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox">
                </span>

                <span class="dvleft mleft15">
                    <strong class="text11">abc123..</strong>
                </span>
                <span class="dvleft mleft15">abc123@gmail.com</span>

            </div><!--sharecon-->
            <div class="sharecon">
                <span class="dvleft">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox">
                </span>

                <span class="dvleft mleft15">
                    <strong class="text11">abc123..</strong>
                </span>
                <span class="dvleft mleft15">abc123@gmail.com</span>

            </div><!--sharecon-->
            <div class="sharecon">
                <span class="dvleft">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox">
                </span>

                <span class="dvleft mleft15">
                    <strong class="text11">abc123..</strong>
                </span>
                <span class="dvleft mleft15">abc123@gmail.com</span>

            </div><!--sharecon-->
            <div class="sharecon">
                <span class="dvleft">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox">
                </span>

                <span class="dvleft mleft15">
                    <strong class="text11">abc123..</strong>
                </span>
                <span class="dvleft mleft15">abc123@gmail.com</span>

            </div><!--sharecon-->
        </div><!--contactlist-->

</div><!--Right Block Ends Here--->

</div>
```

Comment: Please elaborate your question.

Comment: I need to adjust the right div's height as i insert more content in left div box...Please check the given link of jsfiddle...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are a using j Query then try this,

```
$(function(){
    var leftDivHeight = $('.dvleft').height();
    var rightDivHeight = $('.dvright').css({height: leftDivHeight});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery [equalizeCols](https://github.com/johnantoni/jquery.equalizecols) plugin

Comment: will not work in my case.. because i want to adjust the height for Overflow content...:(

Comment: Can we use jquery "
$('.elements').height(Math.max($('#div1').height(), $('#div2').height()));" here...??? if yes.. please some prodive the example...:)